# What is the best way to find out if a file has been added in one of the known directories?

Tags: software-recommendation

I have multiple directory locations known to me.
For example -

```
a/b/dir1/
a/b/dir2/
c/d/dir3/
c/d/dir4/
```

and so on...

There are multiple files in all of these locations. I have to create a data structure that maps all the files in these locations to a unique ID (I can extract this ID form the files themselves). Whenever a new file is added to any of these locations, I have to update my data structure to add a new entry -  of mapping the ID and the file (during compilation).

The way I am planning to solve this is by storing a count of number of files in each folder, e.g.

```
a/b/dir1/         - 100 files
a/b/dir2/         - 50 files
```

and so on...

Every time during compilation, I will do a count of the number of files in each of the directories and if this count is more than the value of the count variable, I will update my data structure to store the mapping of the new file added. I will get to know about the new file added by listing the files by date/time when it is added.

This is the best approach I can think of and it does not seem to be an efficient approach. Can anyone please suggest if this is a correct approach. If not, then what is the better way to tackle this problem.

I hope I have clearly described my problem.
Thanks.

Comment: You can do this on the fly with an event watcher (inotify or python's watchdog ) http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html or https://pypi.org/project/watchdog/ " if this is a correct approach"  That is a matter of opinion. All approaches that do what needs to be done are correct.

Comment: Thanks @Rinzwind. I was planning to use C++ for the implementation, so I will try to use inotify.